# Detecting changes to an input value whith colorpicker - vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, color-picker

I am using a color picker component external from vue2. While it renders nicely and seem to function well with basic usage, I am not able to detect changes to the input value within the vue component. I tried adding @change to the component instance, although it never seems to fire. Any idea why this is? Note, the value change color hex value but never databinding in input

the problem is **item.color never change**.. the *new value from input is assigned to input value from script external colorpicker but never to item.color (never binding)* and cant catch de new value

> **i don't find action them catch them**

> I use @change
> I use @focus

```
<input
                    class="inp input_flexible"
                    :data-did="'A' + (index + 1) + '-colorPicker'"
                    name="color"
                    :id="'color_' + item.TIER_ID"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    type="text"
                    v-model="item.color"
                    v-on:input="cambiarcolor($event)"
                    @click="metodocolor(index, $event)"
                    @blur="metodoblur(index,$event)"
                    @change="cambiarcolor($event)"                   

                  />
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `watch` to do something when `item.color` (`v-model` binding) change.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: {
        color: ""
      },
      doSomething: ""
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
    "item.color"(newValue) {
      this.doSomething = newValue;
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" value="#FFFFFF" v-model="item.color">
  <label>White</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value="#000000" v-model="item.color">
  <label>Black</label>
  <br>
  <span> {{ doSomething }} </span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, the problem is **item.color never change**.. the new value from **input is assigned to input value** from script external colorpicker but never to item.color (never binding)